# Issue getting constructors to inherit properly

Tags: java

Here is my super class

```
public class BankAccount

    {
        double balance;  
        public BankAccount(double initialBalance)
        {
            this.balance = initialBalance;
        }  
        public void deposit(double amount)
        {
            balance += amount;
        }    
        public void withdraw(double amount)
        {
            balance -= amount;
        }    
        public double getBalance()
        {
            return balance;
        }        
        public void transfer(double amount, BankAccount other)
        {
           balance -= amount;
        }    
    }
```

Here is the class that extends it

```
public class CheckingAccount extends BankAccount
{
    int transactionCount;
    double fee;
    public CheckingAccount(double initialBalance)
    {
        this.balance = initialBalance;
        this.transactionCount = 0;        
    }    
    public void deposit(double amount)
    {
        balance += amount;
        transactionCount += 1;
    }
    public void withdraw(double amount)
    {
        balance -= amount;
        transactionCount += 1;
    }    
    public void deductFees()
    {
        if(transactionCount > 3)
        {
            fee = 2.0*(transactionCount-3);
        }    
        balance -= fee;
        transactionCount = 0;
    }    
}
```

The constructor works fine in the super class but when I try to extend that class I get the error that the constructor cannot be applied to the given type, even though I am applying a double to it like it is in the super class.  I am just starting to learn about inheritance in classes so any input is greatly appreciated

Comment: Call `super(whatever)` at the top of your subclass's constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `super` keyword to invoke your parent's constructor.  Your parent class won't be defined without some argument passed to it, so you can do it like this:

```
public CheckingAccount(double initialBalance) {
    super(initialBalance);
    this.transactionCount = 0;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your case is you didn't define default constructor in your superclass. If you will add below constructor, you will not have error.

```
public BankAccount(){
    //default constructor
}
```

When you are trying to instantiate your subclass, implisitly will be first called default constructor of your superclass. So, you may add default consturctor to your BankAccount as I said, and inside write

```
public BankAccount() {
    System.out.println("loading superclass default");
}
```

In your subclass write

```
public CheckingAccount(double initialBalance) {
    System.out.println("loading subclass");
    this.balance = initialBalance;
    this.transactionCount = 0;
}
```

Then try

```
CheckingAccount acc = new CheckingAccount(52);
```

And you will see the result:

```
loading superclass default
loading subclass
```